# Read file and save each line to variable in C

Tags: c, fopen

I'm using fgetc and fopen to read a file in C. I'd like to get the first line in a variable and a second line in a separate variable like so:

```
f = fopen("textfile", "r");

if (!f) {
   printf("error");
} else {
   loop until end of newline and save entire line to a variable
   1st line ==> line1
   2nd line ==> line2
}
```

So if textfile has:

```
hello world
goodbye world
```

line1 = "hello world"
line2 = "goodbye world"

I'm thinking of looping until a \n but how should I store the characters? Think this is a simple question and maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You want to:

I. use `fgets()` to get an entire line, then

II. store the lines into an array of array of `char`.

```
char buf[0x1000];
size_t alloc_size = 4;
size_t n = 0;
char **lines = malloc(sizeof(*lines) * alloc_size);
// TODO: check for NULL

while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f) != NULL) {
    if (++n > alloc_size) {
        alloc_size *= 2;
        char **tmp = realloc(lines, sizeof(*lines) * alloc_size);
        if (tmp != NULL) {
            lines = tmp;
        } else {
            free(lines);
            break; // error
        }

        lines[n - 1] = strdup(buf);
    }
}
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: isn't that `*=` a bit ugly?

Comment: It's clearer than `alloc_size <<= 1;` in my view.  Your answer — your judgement call.

Comment: FWIW: I usually use: `size_t new_size = alloc_size * 2;` and avoid updating `alloc_size` until after the allocation is successful; it arguably makes error recovery more reliable.  You _do_ use `tmp` to avoid losing the reference, but you don't set `n` or `alloc_size` or `lines` to 0 on failure to allocate (though you do free `lines`). These fine points aren't immediately relevant to the OP, I suspect, though a top-quality answer avoids such loose ends whenever possible (even if the whys are not stated).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's right but 1. it's already 12PM here :) 2. Yes, I'm aware that I should be checking the return value of `malloc()` and `strdup()` as well, 3. don't worry, in my own production code I pay attention to slight details, and I expect OP **not to** copy-paste code without first understanding it (although this behavior can be changed by passing me the `-fno-pedantic` flag). Instead of `// error`, probably I should have written `// do more proper error handling here` (since that's what I actually meant).

Answer (score 0):

```
char line[NBRCOLUMN][LINEMAXSIZE];
int i =0; int len;
while (i<NBRCOLUMN && fgets(line[i],sizeof(line[0]),f)) {
    len = strlen(line[î]);
    if(line[len-1] == '\n') line[len-1] = '\0'; // allow to remove the \n  at the end of the line
    i++;
    ....
}
```

Comment: That `sizeof(line)` won't help avoiding buffer overflows... Furhtermore, unless `line` is static, it will quickly cause a stack overflow for any reasonable `NBRCOLUMN` and `LINEMAXSIZE`.

Comment: @H2CO3 it's `sizeof(line[0])` and not `sizeof(line)`

Comment: Now it is. When I wrote my comment, it wasn't.

Comment: @H2CO3 it was a typo and I fixed at the same time you put your comment

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char line1[128];
    char line2[128];
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen("textfile", "r");
    if (!f) {
       printf("error");
    } else {
        fscanf(f, "%127[^\n]\n%127[^\n] ", line1, line2);
        printf("1:%s\n", line1);
        printf("2:%s\n", line2);
        fclose(f);
    }

    return 0;
}
```